# PHP SOAP Client, Error no such operation

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client, nosuchfileexception

I've a problem with my SOAP Client in PHP, I think my request is correct.

My PHP Client SOAP :

```
$soapURL = "http://mylink.fr/mywsdl?wsdl";
$soapParameters = Array('login' => "MyLogin", 'password' => "MyPassword", 'trace' => 1);
try {

   $service=new SoapClient($soapURL, $soapParameters);

   $request = array(
      'address' => array(
         'city' => '',
         'country' => '',
         'department' => '',
         'district' => '',
         'houseNumber' => '',
         'region' => '',
         'road' => '',
         'roadNumber' => '',
         'zipCode' => ''
      ),
      'category' => array(
         'logo' => '',
         'name' => '',
         'reference' => ''
      ),
      'companyName' => '',
      'contactMail' => '',
      'contactName' => '',
      'contactPhone' => '',
      'endTemporary' => '2015-02-15T13:00:10',
      'latitude' => 12.0,
      'longitude' => 12.0,
      'name' => '',
      'radius' => 520,
      'reference' => '',
      'startTemporary' => '2015-02-15T13:00:11',
      'temporary' => 0
   );

   $result = $service->createPOI($request);
} catch(SoapFault $e) {

   echo $service->__getLastRequest();
   echo $e->__toString();

}
```

My SOAP Request :

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.webservices.masternaut.fr/MasterWS/services/POI" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="urn:POI" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" soap-env:encodingstyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soap-env:body>
      <ns1:createpoi>
         <poi xsi:type="ns2:POI">
            <address xsi:type="ns2:Address">
               <city xsi:type="xsd:string"></city>
               <country xsi:type="xsd:string"></country>
               <department xsi:type="xsd:string"></department>
               <district xsi:type="xsd:string"></district>
               <housenumber xsi:type="xsd:string"></housenumber>
               <region xsi:type="xsd:string"></region>
               <road xsi:type="xsd:string"></road>
               <roadnumber xsi:type="xsd:string"></roadnumber>
               <zipcode xsi:type="xsd:string"></zipcode>
            </address>
            <category xsi:type="ns2:PoiCategory">
               <logo xsi:type="xsd:string"></logo>
               <name xsi:type="xsd:string"></name>
               <reference xsi:type="xsd:string"></reference>
            </category>
            <companyname xsi:type="xsd:string"></companyname>
            <contactmail xsi:type="xsd:string"></contactmail>
            <contactname xsi:type="xsd:string"></contactname>
            <contactphone xsi:type="xsd:string"></contactphone>
            <endtemporary xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-02-15T13:00:10</endtemporary>
            <latitude xsi:type="xsd:double">12</latitude>
            <longitude xsi:type="xsd:double">12</longitude>
            <name xsi:type="xsd:string"></name>
            <radius xsi:type="xsd:int">520</radius>
            <reference xsi:type="xsd:string"></reference>
            <starttemporary xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2015-02-15T13:00:11</starttemporary>
            <temporary xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</temporary>
         </poi>
         <overwrite xsi:nil="true"></overwrite>
      </ns1:createpoi>
   </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

The WSDL :

```
<complexType name="PoiCategory">
   <sequence>
      <element name="logo" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="reference" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="Address">
   <sequence>
      <element name="city" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="country" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="department" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="district" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="houseNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="region" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="road" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="roadNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="zipCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
<complexType name="POI">
   <sequence>
      <element name="address" nillable="true" type="tns1:Address"/>
      <element name="category" nillable="true" type="tns1:PoiCategory"/>
      <element name="companyName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="contactMail" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="contactName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="contactPhone" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="endTemporary" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
      <element name="latitude" type="xsd:double"/>
      <element name="longitude" type="xsd:double"/>
      <element name="name" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="radius" type="xsd:int"/>
      <element name="reference" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
      <element name="startTemporary" nillable="true" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
      <element name="temporary" type="xsd:boolean"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
<wsdl:portType name="PoiWS">
   <wsdl:message name="createPOIRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="poi" type="tns1:POI"></wsdl:part>
      <wsdl:part name="overwrite" type="xsd:boolean"></wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="createPOIResponse">
      <wsdl:part name="createPOIReturn" type="xsd:int"></wsdl:part>
   </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="POISoapBinding" type="impl:PoiWS">
   <wsdl:operation name="createPOI">
      <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="createPOIRequest">
         <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mylink.fr/wsdl" use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="createPOIResponse">
         <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mylink.fr/wsdl" use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
   </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="PoiWSService">
   <wsdl:port binding="impl:POISoapBinding" name="POI">
      <wsdlsoap:address location="http://mylink.fr/wsdl"/>
   </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I'm getting this error :

```
SoapFault exception: [Server.userException] No such operation 'createPOI' in /var/www/devt/cronJobs/test.php:58 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/devt/cronJobs/test.php(58): SoapClient->__call('createPOI', Array) 
#1 /var/www/devt/cronJobs/test.php(58): SoapClient->createPOI(Array) 
#2 {main}
```

Can you say me where is my problem and explain me ?

I'm a beginner with SOAP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the WSDL, your request should be something like this:

```
 $request = array(
      'address' => array(
         'city' => '',
         'country' => '',
         'department' => '',
         'district' => '',
         'houseNumber' => '',
         'region' => '',
         'road' => '',
         'roadNumber' => '',
         'zipCode' => ''
      ),
      'category' => array(
         'logo' => '',
         'name' => '',
         'reference' => ''
      ),
      'POI' => array(
         'companyName' => '',
         'contactMail' => '',
         'contactName' => '',
         'contactPhone' => '',
         'endTemporary' => '2015-02-15T13:00:10',
         'latitude' => 12.0,
         'longitude' => 12.0,
         'name' => '',
         'radius' => 520,
         'reference' => '',
         'startTemporary' => '2015-02-15T13:00:11',
         'temporary' => 0
       )
   );
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get this error : `SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'latitude' property`. Why $request should have 3 items ? In the WSDL there is only 2 parameters : "poi" and "overwrite. Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 0):

Always look for Port type in wsdl if you want to know, what are the operations supported by your wsdl.

portType in wsdl is just like class in java which can have multiple "operations" or in world of java "methods".

Your wsdl has one port type i.e. PoiWS but i can't see any operation added in it. While your binding referring to PoiWS porttype which should have operation createPOI,

```
<wsdl:binding name="POISoapBinding" type="impl:PoiWS">
   <wsdl:operation name="createPOI">
```

Please correct your wsdl..
For example portType should look like this,

```
<wsdl:portType name="TestPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="operationName">
        <wsdl:input name="input" message="tns:input"/>
        <wsdl:output name="output" message="tns:output"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

Comment: This is not my WSDL. I'm trying to use a WebService of an other company.
Is it possible to use createPOI without modified the WSDL ?